# Az Cli (2.48.1), Powershell , Python and configparser.DuplicateSectionError systemprofile Duplicate core

Tags: python, azure, powershell

We are using azure cli, 2.48.1.

When our web site executes a shell command to run a powershell script that contains an "az ..." command we get python error that includes following Python-Systemprofile-Problem :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 895, in get_default_cli
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/azlogging.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/extension/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/config.py", line 69, in __init__
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/config.py", line 195, in __init__
  File "configparser.py", line 699, in read
  File "configparser.py", line 1072, in _read
configparser.DuplicateSectionError: While reading from 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\.azure\\config' [line  9]: section 'core' already exists
```

This is repeatable from an administrator console. Running the command "az --version" from inside the directory "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile", and this yields the Python-Systemprofile-Problem output.

In other directories, running the command "az --version" does **not** give this python problem.

*On another machine,* that runs our web site code we don't get the Python-Systemprofile-Problem. An administrator console does not yield the Python-Systemprofile-Problem, and the web site code runs powershell files that contain az commands without the Python-Systemprofile-Problem output.

To try to fix this we have uninstalled azure-cli-2.48.1 , and reinstalled with azure-cli-2.48.1.msi, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Have you tried copying a working `.azure\config` file to the system profile?

Comment: Thank for reply. 1) On the box that is working, the folder is empty, C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.azure.  2) I did try copying  C:\Users\ME\.azure\config to C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.azure\config, BUT we had the the same symptom when at a administrator shell we tried C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile> az --version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the suggestion of colleague (Adam), we chased down this file
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\config
and there was a duplicate [config] section.

Looks like some other install software had come along and added another [config] section

So the file looked like this, note the 2 [config] sections :-

```
[core]
encrypt_token_cache = false

without_prompt

[cloud]
name = AzureCloud

[core]
only_show_errors = true
encrypt_token_cache = false
```

I tried editing the file, and ... still an error, probably because windows editing of a nix file?

I coped the file from another box to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\config, position and things seemed to be solved.

Deleting the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\config file also seems to work!